# Being born in Brihaspati planet

Tags: guru, brihaspati

I was born in the house of Brihaspati and always had a kind of special affection for him like a grandsire of sorts. Is there anything I can do outside of prayer to please him? Would doing good in worldly education please him? Any other rituals one would recommend?

Comment: What is meant by "being born in the house of Brihaspati"?  there are stotra and kavacha for Brihaspati as well as mantras which you can chant though. Brihaspati's over ruling deity is Lord Shiva / Dakshinamurty. According to Tantra, Tara is the Ishta Devata for Brihaspati. So you can worship these deities too.

Comment: In Jyotish I was born in his house or mansion

Comment: Oh  that way ......   :D

Comment: @Rickross Yaaa! :p